# Performance issues with multiple RabbitMq Consumers

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am building a Windows Service in C# that connects to RabbitMq and pulls messages for processing.  It is intended to be multi-threaded, and I have set it up so that via configuration you can specify the RabbitMq connection properties, queues to connect to, messages to fetch, etc.

So far, it is running great. I am running one thread, connected to one queue, and it is processing 500+ messages a second.

Tonight I attempted to add another Queue to process, and I noticed that the speed of processing messages dropped considerably (down to 50 messages/second).

My application reads a config file, which specifies what workers need to be run.
Each worker should be on their own thread, and are started via Task.Factory.StartNew().

Each worker has their own IConnection, IConnectionFactory, and Channel that connects to RabbitMq.

Below is some example code from my worker.
It has a method to EstablishConnection.
You will notice that it create a connection to the RabbitMq servers, then sets up a connection to the Queue.

```
public class Worker
{
    private readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _channel;

    public void EstablishConnection()
    {
     if (_connection == null)
                    {
                        _connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
                        _connection.ConnectionBlocked += ConnectionBlocked;
                        _connection.ConnectionUnblocked += ConnectionUnblocked;
                        _connection.ConnectionRecoveryError += ConnectionRecoveryError;
                        _connection.RecoverySucceeded += RecoverySucceeded;
                    }

                    _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
                    _channel.BasicQos((ushort)_configuration.PrefetchSize, (ushort)_configuration.PrefetchCount, false);

                    _consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
                    _consumer.Received += MessageReceived;
    }
}
```

When just one of these is running, it can process 500+ messages a second.
But when I run two workers connected to different queues, on different threads, it only processes 50 messages a second.

What is also interesting is that in my tests, the second queue I am listening to is empty.  There is nothing in it.

I would expect that it would run 500+ messages on each thread.  Or at least 250 messages on each thread.

As I understand it, the Channels are not thread safe, and we should have a separate channel on each thread.  But should we only have one Connection per application?  Is the issue having a separate connection per thread?

Comment: One additional note.  I tried running an entirely different instance of the application on the same server, and noticed the same issue.  The messages per second dropped dramatically.  I then logged into another machine, and ran the application there (so the app was running from two machines, hitting the same RabbitMq server), and the messages processed per second remained high.

Comment: I think it is ok to have separate connections per thread. Is your prefetch count set to 1?

Comment: Prefetch Count is set to 5.

Comment: There's not enough information to determine what the issue is. The best way to get help is to provide code that reproduces this issue that I could compile and run in my environment.